# How to remove a migration that is timing out from EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

So I recently wrote some code to add some indexes and limit some field sizes, I created a migration and applied it successfully on our local environments.

When the code deploys to the dev Environment (Azure SQL) I am getting a 258 - timeout when trying to apply the same migration, I guess mainly because of the new indexes and having only 10 DTUs there.

As I see i can:

As I see i can:

- scrap the migration all together, add indexes manually
- recreate the db
- figure out a way to increase the time out

The question is: how can I scrap this migration? I can't rollback something that was never aplied and I am not sure if I can simply revert the PR....

Tks

Comment: Well, sure you can increase the timeout, or you can try to identify what part of it is causing the time. Reading the migration output will give you some hints. Separating migrations that contain index creation or that require table-exclusive locks would be nicer. Another way is to get the script from the migration execute it manually and then insert the `__EfMigrationHistory` entry manually and deploy the migrations. So it will skip that migration.

Comment: When making adjustments to indexes and constraints the DB needs to rebuild those indexes and validate the constraints. So for a local development environment with a limited dataset that could take seconds, but in production with more data to churn through it could take significantly longer. Typically when performing schema adjustments on "lean" database servers in Azure you can temporarily increase the Server DTUs, run the migration scripts, then when complete, restore the DTUs.  DTU changes are billed by the hour, so going from an S0 to S4 or so would cost you 1~2 hour's rate difference.